# info icon next to label of a selectInput in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm developing a shiny app and I want to add an "infobox" next to a `selectInput()`. Basically I want to add a small "info" icon to the `selectInput()` label and when a user move the mouse hover the info icon, a box with some text appears. I've found here on stackedoverflow a solution with `tags$span` and `tags$i` and if I add only text it works fine, but if I want to add an html link, or simply another tags (like `tags$strong`), it doesn't work. Here a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    br(),
    selectInput("works", 
                label = tags$span(
                  "This works", 
                  tags$i(
                    class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign", 
                    style = "color:#0072B2;",
                    title = "Further information "
                  )),
                choices = c("a","b")),
    
    selectInput("notwork", 
                label = tags$span(
                  "This not works", 
                  tags$i(
                    class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign", 
                    style = "color:#0072B2;",
                    title = list("Further information ",
                    tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com", "here", .noWS = "after"))
                  )),
                choices = c("a","b")),
    
    selectInput("notwork2", 
                label = tags$span(
                  "Neither this", 
                  tags$i(
                    class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign", 
                    style = "color:#0072B2;",
                    title = p("Further information ",
                                 strong("here"))
                  )),
                choices = c("a","b")),
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

It looks I can't pass any other html tags to that value.

Comment: The code has some issues. Please fix them and update your question.

Comment: I checked the code and runs without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to put HTML in a normal HTML title attribute, which is never supported. what you need is some sort of Tooltip. You can use `bsButton` in combination with `bsPopover` from the `ShinyBS` package. I did not bother for the styling, but I am pretty sure you can get it done from here.

```
# libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    br(),
    selectInput("works", 
                label = tags$span(
                  "This works", 
                  tags$i(
                    class = "glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign", 
                    style = "color:#0072B2;",
                    title = "Further information "
                  )),
                choices = c("a","b")),

    selectInput("worksnow", 
      label = tags$span("This works now too", bsButton("thisworks", label = "", icon = icon("info"), style = "info", size = "extra-small")),
      choices = c("a","b")
    ),
    bsPopover(
      id = "thisworks",
      title = "More information",
      content = paste0(
        "Any HTML can be here ",
        a("ShinyBS", href = "https://ebailey78.github.io/shinyBS/index.html", target="_blank")
      ),
      placement = "right",
      trigger = "hover",
      options = list(container = "body")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

[image]

Comment: I know ShinyBS but I like more the alternative even if it seems that my idea is impossible. Anyway thanks I think I will switch to ShinyBS.

Comment: `ShinyBS` is now `shinyBS`?